# REST API DESIGN - How to overcome the impedance mismatch between a front end client's needs and REST principles?

Tags: rest, web-applications, api-design

Given the following scenario:

1. a RESTful API
2. that RESTful API has permissions/authorizations that can be granted to entire entity collections, and/or to particular entities, i.e. complex role based permission rules.
3. The API is (according to RESTful principles) HATEOS-driven (resource url's are revealed through the API. Once you login and get back the "user" resource, you are able to drive the entire API through links given in responses.
4. A front-end client (web app) that needs to use this API

Imagine now the front-end wants to build a menu. That menu is based on access to particular entities and/or entity collections. For example an "Administration" menu will be shown if the user has access to one of a number of different entities and/or collections.

How do I build the menu? I need to know the permissions the user has in order to build the menu propertly. I don't know all the permissions the user has because it would require walking the url's of the REST API to see all the objects the user has permissions on.

This seems like a tough thing to overcome, but maybe I am missing some obvious technique. How can this impedance mismatch overcome?

Comment: This might be a better fit for [programmers.se]

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe I'm happy to move it there if you think it's more appropriate there...

Comment: Now that there's an answer I think you'd have to flag for mod migration. In general I think more theoretical approach questions sit there and more concrete implementation issues here.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

Your REST API can expose a resource (or it can be a part of the user resource returned after a user has been successfully signed in) which will contain information what resources the user can access and therefore what menu items should be available for this user.

Comment: thanks, I've thought about that too...that's what I'm leaning towards. Is that the only way, you think?

Comment: I guess another option is to use HATEOAS, `/users/<userid>` can return a list of operations that can be called by the currently logged user.

Comment: That would be a huge list though...at least for some users (admin, etc.)